# How to differentiate a matrix?

Tags: derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

The problem I am working on is as such: $q$ is a matrix with $q_{ij}$ corresponding to the delivery by vendor $i$ at location $j$. I wish to get a cost optimization using Lagrangian multipliers. So all my elements in q are variables, but their sum across the row is constant, i.e. the ith vendor delivers a fixed number of deliveries. This is in fact another equation in my optimization problem that I had written as Aq = c. A is a matrix of ones and c is a constant vector.

I am trying to get the Lagrangian in a convex optimization problem. One of the inequalities I have is $g(q) = q - \mu \geq 0$.

$q$ here is an m x n matrix of variables and $\mu$ is a constant m x n matrix.

How would I find $\nabla{g(q)}$?

My initial method was that since $\mu$ is a constant matrix, it would vanish when I differentiate the expression. But it seems like that's wrong? Can anyone please help me out?

Edit 1: I want the differentiation of g(q) with respect to q.

Edit 2: Problem context added.

Comment: The missing information is what you want to differentiate *with respect to*.  In other words, what is $q$ a function of, that you want to find its gradient?  Yes as $\mu$ signifies a constant matrix, it's gradient is zero.  So just the gradient of $q$ matters.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your comment. I wish to differentiate g(q) w.r.t q (made the changes in the question). The direction of my problem suggests the derivative should be a matrix of ones instead of zeros like my intuition tells me.

Comment: If we think of the entries in $q$ as independent variables, then the gradient of $q$ should probably be a higher dimensional object, like $m\times n$ by $m\times n$, to represent the rate of change of each entry of $q$ with respect to every entry of $q$.  Some of those rates of change are ones and most of them are zeros.  However knowing what problem you are trying to solve would allow Readers to make better suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you @hardmath. That seems helpful. I have added context about my problem in my post. Please review that and let me know if I can proceed in a better way.